# WooCommerce search for Product Variation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I need to get the ID of all variations containing attributes within a category.

At the moment I have the following.

```
$taxQuery[] = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'field' => 'term_id',
    'terms' => $id
);

$args = array(
    'post_status' => array('private', 'publish'),
    'tax_query' => array([
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_avanti-door-size',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => ($height - 5) . 'mm x ' . ($width - 4) . 'mm',  ($height - 5) . 'mm x ' . ($width - 3) . 'mm',
            'operator' => 'IN',
        ]
     ),
    'limit' => 100000,
);

$products = wc_get_products($args);
```

But it returns the Product ID and not the variation ID.

How can I achieve this?